# Take the result of an SQL query and move it to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-insert

I am playing with two tables.

Table one has a column named "person_id". If person_id 1 makes a second comment, the person_id shows up twice and so on..
example here

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMyXM.png]

I made this query which returns the total comments by a single person_id like this:

```
SELECT person_id, COUNT(comment) AS total_comments
FROM comments
GROUP BY person_id
;
```

The return of the query above is :

```
person_id   total_comments
   3             1
   1             2
```

How do I move the total_comments info above into into a different table?
also what kind of JOIN would this be for my knowledge. Inner? Left?

Comment: [link]  https://i.imgur.com/5unvq37.png

Comment: How are you going to maintain the new table? Will you clear it every time before inserting data or do you want to combine insert and update depending on if the person_id already exist or not?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (PERSON_ID, TOTAL_COMMENTS)
SELECT PERSON_ID, COUNT(COMMENT) AS TOTAL_COMMENTS 
FROM COMMENTS GROUP BY PERSON_ID ;
```

Comment: I am getting this error..                                                                                    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COMMENT"
LINE 2: SELECT PERSON_ID COUNT COMMENT AS  
                                                                ^                TOTAL_COMMENTS